# Is it possible to create subsets of a dataframe for each value in a column of a master dataframe?

Tags: r, automation, subset

I have a large dataframe (just over 8,500,000 cells in total) and I need to create some subsets of this dataframe based on the values in a specific column.

I am aware that I can create said subsets by hand and am happy doing this when there are only a few values.  At present, I obtain the unique values:

```
table(df$ColumnX)
```

and then construct the individual dataframes from there as there are only a few values:

```
df.subset1 <- df[df$ColumnX == "Subset1", ]
df.subset2 <- df[df$ColumnX == "Subset2", ]
...
df.subsetX <- df[df$ColumnX == "SubsetX", ]
```

But when there are significantly more unique values is where I see a problem which would require my computer's processing power to achieve my goal in a timely manner.

What I want to know is if this process can be automated.

Something like this is what I am hoping to achieve:

```
- List values in Column X
- Create a new dataframe/subset for each value in Column X
```

Or:

```
for(all unique values in Column X)
    create a new dataframe
end for
```

Therefore, I would have something like this based on the values of `ColumnX`:

```
df.subset1
df.subset2
...
df.subsetX
```

Comment: Just use `split` i.e. `dflist <- split(df, df$ColumnX)`. This will give you a list of data.frames

Comment: I see.  And how do I extract the data.frames from the list?

Comment: If you take the example of `x <- split(iris, iris$Species)`, you can extract the list elements using either `x$setosa` or `x[[1]]` or `x[["setosa"]]`

Comment: Some additional context is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3521006

Comment: Dont extract them at all. Keeping them in a list is a much better option and will streamline your further analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Sample Dataset:

```
zz <- "A1   A2   A3   A4   A5
Z    Z    1    10   12
E    Y    10   12    8
D    X    2    12   15
Z    Z    1    10   12
D    X    2    14   16"
df <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)

s1 <- split(df, df$A1)
list2env(s1,envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

The List get stored as dataframe in your environment

```
> D
  A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
3  D  X  2 12 15
5  D  X  2 14 16
> E
  A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
2  E  Y 10 12  8
> Z
  A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
1  Z  Z  1 10 12
4  Z  Z  1 10 12
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @docendo that in general, keeping the dataframe in a list is in general more efficient.

But for record sake, you could also use `assign`:

```
list_index <- list(1:5, 6:8, 10:13)

for(i in 1:length(list_index)){ # i <- 1
  assign(paste0("df_", i), mtcars[list_index[i][[1]], ])
}
```